# Best Method for Preventing a user from voting multiple times in a Multi-Tenant environment

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies

First off, I know there are many related questions being posted on the topic of Prevention of users from casting multiple votes for a single topic or area. I have read mostly all of them that have acquired answers. But my scenario is slightly different from those I've read and I am looking for an appropriately good method as an answer or recommendation.

My site is a Multi-tenant environment. So users may vote on other users site contributions but they must be logged in to do that. Reading other posts I think I've covered this aspect of the problem.

So if I have, say 10 users each having their own site contributions and Member#1 of those Users votes for Member#2. I cannot see how I might go about implementing cookies to solve the problem of multiple votes from the same user and still allow Member#1 to vote for Member#3. Hope this is making sense.

In short, given the above scenario; I want to prohibit Member#1 from casting another vote for Member#2 but not from casting a vote for Member#3 or 4 or 5 and etc. Unless they've already voted for those Members.

I need an elegant yet fairly simple way of doing this if its possible. I thought of using some database tables to achieve this but as the site grows this seems like it could potentially become an unreasonably large amount of data to enforce such a simple rule.

Cookies sound good but I'm not certain how I'd handle managing the rules so as to not entirely prohibit the user from making any votes at all and allow only those for which they haven't already made a vote.

I am using MVC4 with the Raty Star voting system.

Comment: I think the only way to achieve this would be with a database, or some other form of persisted store  (flat files). If you set a cookie, a user could easily clear cookies, and vote again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this client-side. Instead, when the user votes, send the vote to your server and record it server-side (almost certainly in a database). Yes, that server-side store (DB table or whatever you use) will grow in size over time, but you cannot rely on *any* client-side mechanism for doing this. Your only way to prevent repeated votes is to store the votes that have been made, and the only place you can reasonably do that is where users can't get at it.

Comment: Thanks guys. I was actually hoping there would be an alternate solution as the answer, but it is what it is. I'll implement the logic and persist it to the DB.